# Cannot run Pop!_OS in qemu on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, virtualization, raspberry-pi, qemu, pop-os

I've downloaded the `Pop!_OS` iso file on a Raspberry Pi to run on qemu, but when I run the file with:

```
qemu-system-i386 -L . -hda pop.cow -net nic,model=pcnet -net user -cpu pentium -soundhw all -vga cirrus -m 1G -cdrom pop-os_21.04_amd64_intel_9.iso -boot d
```

In the terminal, I get this error:

```
SeaBIOS (version 1.12.0-1)

iPXE (http://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 C980 PCI2.10 PP PMM+3FF90100+3FED0100 C980

Booting from DVD/CD.

ISOLINUX 6.03 20171017 ETCD Copyright (C) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al
Failed to load ldlinux.c32

Boot failed: press a key
to retry...
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you verified the pop os ISO isnt corrupt ?

Comment: I think you can't run a X86 or X86_64 VM in a RPi (ARM). And, unlike Ubuntu, Pop has no releases for ARM.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you for the information.